# Missing Left-Border in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, border

For this report created in HTML & CSS the left borders are disappearing in IE 7 & 6.  They show up correctly in IE 8, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc.

I am applying the style with three different CSS classes:

```
.LeftBorder
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.LeftBorderHeadingShaded
{
    background-color: gray;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.noshadeLeftBorder
{
    background-color: white;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

And those classes are applied to specific TR and TD tags, but the left border fails to show up on any of those.  Some of the bottom borders are missing to, but that isn't as big of a deal.

I made a screen shot showing IE 7, 6 and 8 side by side.  I circled the problem area.  Here is the [full HTML/CSS](http://mckeeth.org/test/order.html).

[image: Internet Explorer sucks at CSS]
<sub>(source: [mckeeth.org](http://www.mckeeth.org/test/missing-border.png))</sub>

Comment: Keep in mind IE6 has trouble with multiple classes on the same element. It doesn't seem to be the reason to your problem because it doesn't work in IE 7 either but still.

Comment: I am only applying one class per element. Different elements just have different classes.

Comment: To clarify what Pekka is talking about its not elements having multiple classes like `<div class="class-one class-two class-three"></div>` is a matter of using multiple class selectors in the css like `div.class-one.class-two {/* properties */}`. This selector should evaluate properly (And does in FF, Safari) but doesnt work in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Well that selector simply means "apply the properties to elements of the type `td` that are children of a `tr` element with the the class `LeftBorder`". If thats not right on to your structure i apologize for the confusion i only glanced at you code in fire bug and saw a tr with the class LeftBorder. Bottom line is though you need to be applying border to `td` and/or `table`... not `tr`.

Well first of all i dont think youre supposed to apply borders to a `tr` they are on the td so you need to target them like `tr.LeftBorder td`

Comment: The solution was to apply the *LeftBorder* styles to the first **TD** in the **TR**. Of course some of those styles have other formatting too, but it will work.